# how to make a list of first characters in from list of strings

Tags: python, arrays, string

Suppose I have a list of strings say

```
['abc' , 'def', 'ghi']
```

How do I convert it into a list of arrays like

```
[['a','d','g'],['b','e','h'],['c','f','i']]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? This should be included in your question to give us a starting point for helping you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `zip()`:

using list comprehension:

```
In [7]: lis=['abc' , 'def', 'ghi']

In [9]: [list(x) for x in zip(*lis)]
Out[9]: [['a', 'd', 'g'], ['b', 'e', 'h'], ['c', 'f', 'i']]
```

using `map()`:

```
In [11]: map(list,zip(*lis))
Out[11]: [['a', 'd', 'g'], ['b', 'e', 'h'], ['c', 'f', 'i']]
```

Comment: Also note that `zip(*lis)` should be enough if the OP is satisfied with tuples instead of lists (i.e. isn't going to mutate them), which is likely to be the case.

Comment: It works. I have done it by looping it without any special methods like zip. But wanted to know if there is any special method that python has. Thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension and `zip`:

```
l = ['abc' , 'def', 'ghi']
l = [list(x) for x in zip(*l)]
print l

>>> [['a','d','g'],['b','e','h'],['c','f','i']]
```